# How to create the back slash path for file system sink in ADF copy activity?

Tags: csv, escaping, azure-data-factory

I am trying to write a csv to a [windows file system sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system?tabs=data-factory#sample-linked-service-and-dataset-definitions)
using this design
[image: design idea]

while previewing the csv delimited text, it's showing fine
[image: preview csv]

but output of look up comes like

```
{
    "firstRow": {
        "file_name": "file_TEST.csv",
        "begin_dir": "\\\\msf.dom",
        "sub_dir": "\\shared\\Workspace\\1 - abc",
        "end_dir": "\\legacy folder\\NewFolder"
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime..."
```

and same in the variable output.

How to form the root path for the host without the doubling backslash?
My required rootpath for the linked service is the concat of begin_dir and sub_dir
`\\msf.dom\shared\Workspace\1 - abc`

[image: sample lookup reference file]

I tried to use replace function to `\\` to `\` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

- There is no need to replace the `\\` with `\`.  The extra `\` is because it is escaping the actual `\` character present as a value in the string.
- The following is a demonstration where you can see from the errors that the values are being read as required.
- I have a lookup with debug output as shown in the below image:

[image]

- Now, when I pass the value `begin_dir` to host in the linked service, I get the following error (As I do not have the resource). But, you can see the value that is being taken as host (dir value as xxx and filename as yyy.csv).

[image]

- When I give the begin_dir, sub_dir and file_name from lookup and then I get an error message where you can see how the pas is being taken:

[image]

Comment: The copy activity was successful when I tried but it was showing creating the file in the path. Here in your error the host is starting with D. I think it's happening with me, it's trying to find end dir under C folder and not under host. Could you please add 3 variables for the  host, file path (var directory/var filename) ?

Comment: The values I gave for host, dir, path are "\\\\msf.dom",  "\\shared\\Workspace\\1 - abc" and "file_TEST.csv" respectively.

Comment: ok, I ended up making the host path and dir path to end with backslash and end dir with just the folder name (no slashes anywhere). This way it worked.